# C++ Написать функцию, которая находит в файле самое длинное число в строке

Tags: c++, файлы

Текст задания такой - напишите функцию, которая находит и печатает самую длинную строку чисел в файле. Если есть несколько строк такой длины, распечатайте ту, которая представляет наибольшее число. Предскажите, что числовые строки могут быть произвольно длинными. Сообщите соответствующим образом, если в файле вообще нет цифр. Например, «alpha321beta456gamma123» → 456.

Мой код такой, это все, что я сумела написать:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string longestInteger(string str, fstream &f1) {
    int count = 0, max = 0, pos = -1, pre_pos, pre_len, len = 0;
    int i;
    while (getline (f1, str)) {
        cout << str;
        pre_pos = pos;
        pre_len = len;
        count = 0;
        len = 0;
    }

//    for (int i = 0; i < &f1; i++) {
//         pre_pos = pos;
//         pre_len = len;
//         count = 0;
//         len = 0;

        if (isdigit(str[i]))
            pos = i;

        while (isdigit(str[i])) {
            count++;
            i++;
            len++;
        }

        if (count > max) {
            max = count;
        }
        else {
            pos = pre_pos;
            len = pre_len;
        }
    }
    return (str.substr(pos, len));
}

int main() {

    ifstream fin ("in.txt");
    fstream f1;
    f1.open("in.txt", ios::in);
    string str;

    if (f1.is_open()) {
        f1 << "alpha321beta456gamma123";
        int l = str.length();
        cout << longestInteger(str, &f1);
    } else {
        cout << "Nevar atvērt failu!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что с вашим кодом не так? Выдает не то, что вы ожидали увидеть? Тогда приведите данные, которые находятся в файле, данные которые возвращает ваша программа и то, что вы ожидали увидеть. И у вас скобка `}` лишняя после первого `while`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объясню, как можно сделать:

1. Для начала заголовок функции лучше изменить на `string longestInteger(fstream& f)`

   То есть функция принимает поток и возвращает результат типа `string`
2. Как я понял вам нужно найти максимальную числовую последовательность во всем файле. Т.к. длина последовательности может быть очень большой и не помещаться даже в `unsigned long long int`, то будет хранить число в виде строки и сравнивать соответственно, как строки.
3. Вам пригодится 5 переменных.

   1. Я оставил `int i`, но лучше изменить, на более понятное что-то типа `index`. Это просто будет итератор по считанной из файла строке
   2. `int str_size` пригодится часто получать размер считанной строки, так что лучше после после чтения строки, сохранить её длину.
   3. `string line` сюда будет считываться строка из файла
   4. `string max_num = ""` думаю понятно, что переменная отвечает за максимальное число в файле, её мы и будем возвращать в конце функции.
   5. `string num = ""` сюда мы будем заносить найденное число, а потом сравнивать в `max_num`.
4. Первое, что нужно сделать это считать строку из файла, у вас есть этот момент в коде. `getline(f, line)` в нашем случае. (И понятное дело в условии цикла `while`)
5. После чтения строки, как у вас в коде, можно вывести строку в консоль, а так же нужно обнулить счетчик `i` и присвоить `str_size  line.size()`
6. Теперь надо проанализировать считанную строку.

   Пишем цикл `while(i < str_size)`. В нем я привык сначала находить начало числовой последовательности, то есть циклом проходить по строке, пока не наткнуть на цифру. Мне удобней использовать такую проверку `line[i] < '0' || line[i] > '9'` вместо функции `isdigit`

   ```
   while (i < str_size && (line[i] < '0' || line[i] > '9'))
       ++i;
   ```

   После цикла выше `i` будет равен или индексу первого вхождения цифры или `str_size`.
7. Теперь запишем так же в цикле идет по строке, пока символ является цифрой и записываем его в `num`

   ```
   while (i < str_size && line[i] >= '0' && line[i] <= '9') {
       num += line[i];
       i++;
   }
   ```
8. Осталось всего лишь сравнить две строки. Но для этого не подойдет просто функция `strcmp` или оператор сравнения у `string`. Т.к. они не обращают внимания на длину строки.

   Написал не большую функцию:

   ```
   //Возвращает -1, если left < right
   //Возвращает 1, есть right > left
   //И 0 если они равны
   int str_compare(string& left, string& right) {
       if (left.size() < right.size()) return -1;
       if (left.size() > right.size()) return 1;
       return strcmp(left.c_str(), right.c_str());
   }
   ```

   Если `max_num` меньше `num`, то присваиваем `max_num = num`, тут думаю все понятно.
9. Очищаем `num = ""`
10. Возвращаем `max_num` после все циклов.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил идею, если вам нужно, то вы прочитаете и поймете, если же нет, тогда извините полного кода я просто не скину :)

Comment: За что -реп? :(

Comment: Большое спасибо <3